# Error with solution path in MSbuild in Jenkins Freestyle build

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following error when using MSBuild in a Freestyle project in Jenkins

The workflow I want is as follows:

- git clone repo into workspace (SUCCESS)
- MSbuild the SLN file from the repo (apparently fails.
- Once the build succeeds, moves files to a network mapped folder

I have the MSbuild plugin installed, and I paste the entire path to the SLN file that exists after it clones the repo.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here's the entire build log:

````
Building in workspace C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\TAPPISAFE-Pipeline
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential JenkinsGitbucket
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://agile.tappi.org/gitbucket/git/root/TAPPISAFE.git
 > git.exe init C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\TAPPISAFE-Pipeline # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://agile.tappi.org/gitbucket/git/root/TAPPISAFE.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.11.1.windows.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Jenkins Gitbucket
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress -- https://agile.tappi.org/gitbucket/git/root/TAPPISAFE.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://agile.tappi.org/gitbucket/git/root/TAPPISAFE.git # timeout=10
 > git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 03661da9c578e2dfc33ca5594b3e16dd8cf0650a (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 03661da9c578e2dfc33ca5594b3e16dd8cf0650a # timeout=10
Commit message: "Merge pull request #1 from root/brenden-master"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk 03661da9c578e2dfc33ca5594b3e16dd8cf0650a # timeout=10
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe Tappisafe.Web.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\TAPPISAFE-Pipeline
[TAPPISAFE-Pipeline] $ cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe Tappisafe.Web.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
Active code page: 1252
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.8.3761.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: Tappisafe.Web.sln
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE```
````

Comment: Switch: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\TAPPISAFE-Pipeline\Tappisafe.Web.sln

That doesn't look like a valid folder. I doubt you got your .sln there :). Can you give more information about your Jenkins and MSBuild setup?

Comment: So in the MSbuild settings I was providing the exact path to the SLN file, which did exist. I also tried supplying the relative path (inside the workspace) to the SLN file, but its giving the same error.

The project simply clones a git repo, then MSbuild builds the corresponding SLN file, or rather, its supposed to.

Comment: For FreeStyle Jenkins job, after each job build done you can check the files/folder in job's    workspace. Like the source code file clone from repo, or build artifact etc.  So you can open your Jenkins job and click the `WorkSpace` link right of the sider bar and close page top.  To confirm you give correct file of `Tappisafe.Web.sln` to msbuild

Comment: and yes, the solution file is there, so I'm not seeing what the issue is. "Tappisafe.Web.sln" is a valid file in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by xcopying all of my workspace files into a directory I could write too, and problem solved.